# O que é e para que serve a palavra reservada "strictfp"?

Tags: java, ponto-flutuante, palavras-reservadas

Desconheço essa palavra chave, nunca vi um exemplo de código em que ela fosse usada. Até que descobri hoje a existência dela ao ler alguns livros sobre Java, no entanto não ficou claro qual a utilidade. O que é `strictfp`? Para que serve? Quando usar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É para tentar garantir compatibilidade entre arquiteturas.

O modo *non strict FP* foi criado para dar maior precisão em cálculos em arquiteturas com implementações de ponto flutuante com maior precisão da que o Java usa. Isto é o padrão do Java.

Mas isto trouxe problemas de compatibilidade de valores calculados dependendo de onde a execução é feita.

Fonte: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictfp).

Então você deve usá-la sempre que souber que precisa dos mesmos resultados não importa onde esteja rodando a aplicação.

Quase sempre isto não é necessário afinal tipos de ponto flutuante binário já não tem precisão absoluta. Tem precisão apenas suficiente. Então muda pouco na maior parte dos casos.

Daí nasce a expressão "Write-Once-Get-Equally-Wrong-Results-Everywhere".

Fonte: [resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/517996/221800).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Sugestão de melhoria da resposta: strictfp pode *diminuir* a precisão e a velocidade de execução, sua vantagem é ser  previsível, executando igual em qualquer processador, seja ele x86, ARM, SPARC, etc.

Comment: @marcus obrigado pela observação mas o problema era outro. Eu estava falando do *default* atual do Java para mostrar porque foi necessário criar o `strictfp`.

Comment: Sim, vi sua edição (adição do “non”) e agora entendi que a intenção era explicar como funciona **sem** strictfp.

Answer (score 4):

O stricfp é usado para criar a chamada precisão estendida. 
Essa precisão estendida foi criada devido a necessidade de alguns programadores necessitarem de computação mais precisa sobre valores de ponto flutuante. 
EX: 
Dada a seguinte instrução:

```
double result = val1 * val2 / val3;
```

O que acontecia era o seguinte: muitos processadores da Intel computavam val1 * val2 e deixavam o resultado em um registrador de 80bits e somente após a divisão por val3, eles truncavam de volta para 64bits. Essa situação gerava um resultado mais preciso e menos propenso a estouro de exponentes, mas o resultado era diferente das computações que utilizavam 64bits todo o tempo.

O que aconteceu foi, que a especificação da Máquina Virtual Java exigia que todas as computações intermediárias fossem truncadas, ou seja, mesmo que o processador pudesse realizar a computação intermediária gravando o resultado em um registrador de 80bits, a JVM fazia com que todas as operações intermediárias fossem truncadas, o que causou um descontentamento na comunidade JAVA, pois tornava a operação mais lenta (computação com truncamento é mais demorada que computações mais precisas) e tornava mais propenso ao estouro de exponentes.

A criação do strictfp foi justamente para atender a essa questão da otimização do desempenho e também pela questão da precisão dos resultados. Agora, caso o usuário necessite de uma precisão maior em seus resultado e melhor desempenho, ele pode usar o strictfp.

fonte: http://javafree.uol.com.br/topic-863961-Uso-do-strictfp.html