# Para que serve e onde devo usar "strictfp"

Tags: java, java-9

Estava lendo a especificação do Java 9 e me deparei com a keyword `strictfp`, lí para que serve só que não ficou claro.

Pra que serve isso e onde devo aplicar?

Porque não é tão utilizado nos programas hoje?

Porque não foi removido (caso isso não seja utilizado)?

Comment: Eu tinha visto essa resposta porém não esclareceu todas minhas dúvidas.  Editei a pergunta.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45455/64969 ; removi meu voto de fechamento devido à edição, que me deixou claro ser outro ponto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe uma norma técnica chamada [IEEE 754](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dupla_precis%C3%A3o_no_formato_de_ponto_flutuante), que define como deve ser feita na prática a representação da precisão dupla em ponto flutuante. Em Java, essa representação é materializada no tipo de dado `double`. Em outras palavras, a representação dessa norma técnica é seguida à risca quando se trabalha com `double` em Java.

Sempre e quando a JVM controla e realiza operações envolvendo `double`, tem-se a garantia de que a dupla precisão ocorre da maneira como deve ocorrer (segue a norma IEEE 754). Porém, por questões de otimização e velocidade, pode acontecer de a JVM delegar essas operações ao processador da máquina e é aí que as coisas podem se complicar porque, como sabemos, há vários tipos de processador no mercado, cada um com sua arquitetura e características específicas, incluindo a forma como eles lidam com cálculos envolvendo pontos flutuantes e que não necessariamente seguem a norma técnica citada anteriormente. Isso significa que não há garantia de que um mesmo cálculo, envolvendo os mesmos números, gerem sempre a mesma precisão em processadores diferentes (ou seja, o resultado não é determinístico) e isso pode ser um problema se você, por exemplo, tem um programa de aplicação matemática que necessita de extrema precisão.

Para garantir que um cálculo com esses números sejam sempre realizados pela JVM e não delegados ao processador (eliminando-se então a possibilidade de resultados diferentes dependendo do processador), utiliza-se, nas variáveis que serão utilizados nesse cálculo, a keyword `strictfp`. Isso garante que, independentemente da plataforma em que seu programa seja executado, um cálculo com ponto flutuante será determinístico (dados os mesmos dados de entrada, o resultado será sempre o mesmo).

Para 99,9% dos desenvolvedores, entretanto, essas eventuais diferenças não importam, visto que a maioria das aplicações desenvolvidas por eles não necessitam de tal precisão, e isso explica por que você dificilmente se depara com essa keyword sendo utilizada, mas não se engane, ela é usada sim, provavelmente em aplicações científicas, como aceleradores de partículas ou mesmo de modelagem matemática.